# Output for a String method of alternating characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am trying to create a String output in a method where two genetic strands are compared by their individual characters (A, C, T, G) and the dominant base of the two strands (whichever has a higher value), is returned. So far, I have:

```
public String getDominant() {
    int STRAND_LENGTH = 5;
    String strands[0] = "ACCTG";
    String strands[1] = "CCGTA";

    for (int i = 0; i < STRAND_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (strands[0].charAt(i) > strands[1].charAt(i)) {
           System.out.print(strands[0].charAt(i));
        }
        else if (strands[0].charAt(i) < strands[1].charAt(i)) {
            System.out.print(strands[1].charAt(i));
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(strands[0].charAt(i));
        }
        return;
    }
```

In my code, strands[0] and strands[1] are initialized outside of the method in a constructor. I am just setting them here for clarity.

I understand that I need to return a String, but I am unsure as to how to turn the output of the for loop into a variable that can be passed.

When I use this in Java visualizer, the expected dominant strand CCGTG is returned as a void output, but I need to get a String to use in other methods.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to build up the return value.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

//... in your loop/if blocks ...
result.append(strands[0].charAt(i));

return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to put your return statement outside the for-loop, as you only want to return at the very end.

You can use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to keep track of the result:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < STRAND_LENGTH; i++) {
    result.append((char)Math.max(strands[0].charAt(i), strands[1].charAt(i)));
}
return result.toString();
```

(I also replaced your `if` statements with a single method call. I think you understand what the `max` method does.)